# ZF Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Module With and withouht a module default route

Tags: zend-framework, zend-route, zend-framework-modules, zend-router

I have a project witch I started without using a module structure in ZF 1 now I need to place a module structure
for managing users (makes more sense to me).

My problem the "default" route should try to go with :controller/:action/:id and the module route
should go with :module/:controller/:action/:id the default from ZF 1 is to use the above without the :id
but my "logic" requires the :id field, how can I make this work?

What I've trying came to:

```
    protected function _initModuleAutoload()
{
    $modelLoader = new Zend_Application_Module_Autoloader(
                    array('namespace' => 'DM',
                        'basePath' => APPLICATION_PATH . '/modules/default')
                    , array('namespace' => 'UM',
                'basePath' => APPLICATION_PATH . '/modules/users')
    );

    $modelLoader->addResourceType('service', 'services', 'Service');
    $modelLoader->addResourceType('serviceplugin', 'services/plugins', 'Service_Plugin');

    return $modelLoader;
}

public function _initFrontController()
{
    $front = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
    $router = $front->getRouter();

    $route1 = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route(
                    ':module/:controller/:action/:id/',
                    array(
                        'id' => '\d+'
                        , 'module' => 'default'
                        , 'controller' => 'index'
                        , 'action' => 'index'
                    )
    );

    $router->addRoute('default', $route1);

    $front->addModuleDirectory(APPLICATION_PATH . "/modules/");

    $front
            ->registerPlugin(new Far_Access_Plugin_Identity(), 1)
            ->registerPlugin(new Far_Access_Plugin_Access(), 2)
            ->throwExceptions(true)
    ;

    return $front;
}
```

Also tried to create a second route for users instead of default but did not work.

Any ideas? What am I doing wrong?

**A help from irc in freenode was given in channel #zftalk when I provided this link.**

> Bittarman: crash82: add requirements to the id, so it has to be [\d]+
>   Bittarman: or, just add an instance of
>   Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Module chained to
>   Zend_Controller_Router_Route with just :id in it, with a default set
>   for id like false.
>   Bittarman: also, _initModuleAutoload, is pointless
>   Bittarman: having your 'default' module in the modules dir, is kinda
>   wrong
>   Bittarman: and you stop the frontcontroller resource from
>   working by having an _initFrontController
>   Bittarman: so resources.frontController will no longer work.
>
> crash82: hum... So many problems :( , so I can just place the
>   "default" module into the application directory and any other modules
>   can continue to be loaded from the modules / path ?
>
> Bittarman: yes :)
>
> crash82: going to try that 
>   Bittarman: and, each module which has a bootstrap, supplies its own module resource loader
>   Bittarman: so, if you go creating more like that, you end up with two for each module.
>   Bittarman: you'd be surprised how many people do tht.
>   Bittarman: s/tht/that/

Comment: The default routing in the current version of ZF always tests for module when routing. Adding a module will not effect routing if you are using default routes. Just add the module as the first parameter and it should work. if you want, check out thecode in `Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Module`

Comment: Yes that is part of the answer. :-) Thank you

Answer (score 0):

When I need to pass a parameter in a url in my scripts I use one of a couple of methods. For most simple things there is no real need to create a new route.

1. `<a href="/music/index/album/id/<?php echo $variable->id ?>"><?php echo $track->album ?></a>`. Pass the parameter as /`id/album_id`
2. use the url() view helper : `<?php echo $this->url(array('controller' => 'index', 'action' => 'index', 'id' => $variable->id)); ?>` This helper will also take a module as the first parameter.
3. The first 2 work in view scripts, to do the same thing in a controller you can use the reidrector action helper: `$this->getHelper('Redirector')->gotoSimple('action'=> 'someAction', 'controller' => 'someController', 'module' => 'someModule', array('id' => $id );` with controller, module and params being optional with a default of `NULL`.
4. or you can use use the action utility method _forward() : `$this->_forward($action, $controller, $module, array($params))` this same syntax as gotoSimple() has.

There are other ways to accomplish this kind of routing, I'll leave it to you to find the rest, but you might start with [Action Helpers](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.actionhelpers.html), [utility methods](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.action.html#zend.controller.action.utilmethods) and [view helpers](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.view.helpers.html)

Comment: yes, but I don't want to specify the id/1 just the /1, I'm lazy... :)

Comment: one way or another your going to have to specify the variables, your choice on how you do it.